# Creating a custom object (and tab) to host a library of content

Tags: custom-object

I am trying to create a tab that will have links to pdfs hosted on salesforce. Essentially, a sort of dashboard with content that my users can easily view and open. It needs to be easy for my users to view the content I have posted but I am not wanting them to have any ability to edit it (that part I know how to do).

So far, I have created a custom object (named it 'Marketing Library'). However, I am a little stuck on the best way to put links or files in.

What is the best way to create this type of thing?

Comment: why not put all the files in a Library and give users access to the Library (available on the Files tab)